# Bootstrap alert open from left, close to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an alert is it´s showed in the navbar. What I would like is achieve an effect where the alert arrive form the left of the navbar, and when I close, instead of fade out just disappear from the right.

I dont know if that´s an effect that bootstrap can provide by the css framework.

Here is my current code

the html:

```
<div id="msgbox_success" class="alert alert-success alert-position hidden">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <spring:message code='msg.saved'/>
</div>
```

and here my js

```
function showMessageBoxSuccess() {
    console.log("Displaying msgbox_success");
    if ($("#msgbox_success").is(":visible")) {
        $("#msgbox_success").hide();
    }
    $("#msgbox_success").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#msgbox_success").show();
    $("#msgbox_success").delay(callbackAction.SUCCESS_TIMEOUT).fadeOut();
}
```

Like I said I would like to have an animation instead use show, to show the alert from the left. And when I click in close another animation instead hide, to hide the alert moving it to the right.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide some code so that folks can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to give this another shot.  I setup a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhaq052L/2/)** example that I think is similar to what you want.  It has JS and CSS that will get the job done. In the example, I have a button that triggers the alert to come in from the left.  Then, clicking the close button in the alert will send the alert offscreen to the right.

```
$("#theButton").click(function(){
    $("#msgbox_success").removeClass("hidden").attr("aria-hidden", false);
    $("#msgbox_success").animate({left: '75%'}, "slow");
}); 

$(".close").click(function(){
    $("#msgbox_success").animate({left: '150%'}, "slow");

    var adjustMsgBox = function(){
        $("#msgbox_success").addClass("hidden").attr("aria-hidden", true);
    };
    setTimeout(adjustMsgBox, 2000);
});
```

There might be a better way to do this, but I think this will point you in the right direction.  The messageContainer will be your navbar, so adjust CSS accordingly.  Hope this is more of what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Bootstrap plugin that you could maybe take advantage of called [Bootstrap Notify](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/) (formerly Bootstrap Growl).  Another idea is [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/), but that is more modal driven.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I read about it, but I would rather dont introduce anything else, but doing by css or something like that. Thanks anyway